# Python Selenium Code behaving differently depending on calling mode

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I've tripped on a very easy to reproduce code that's driving me crazy.

I'm trying to **take a picture of the screen** after **entering a container code** in a website form, using Python and PhantomJS webdriver (selenium).

The code that makes it possible is quite short, and reproducing it in the console works fine. But if this same code is within a function or a script, it doesn't behave the same.

**Here is the working code**, that works for me writing it line by line in the console:
(Python version 2.7.9, selenium 2.53.6)

```
> python

from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1280, 1024)
driver.get('http://www.track-trace.com/container')
driver.find_element_by_name('number').clear()
driver.find_element_by_name('number').send_keys('CGMU5109933')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="commit" and @value="Track direct"]').click()
driver.save_screenshot('./x.png')
```

However, this same code inside a function or a script only behaves the same until it reaches the click.
**It freezes while loading**, and the screenshot shows just that. 
It doesn't matter what type of wait I try, implicit or explicit, the loading button won't end.

Here is the same code inside a function in foo.py module to make trying it easier.

**The picture that is taken won't match the picture taken by the above code.**

```
# foo.py
from selenium import webdriver
def try_it():
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    driver.set_window_size(1280, 1024)
    driver.get('http://www.track-trace.com/container')
    driver.find_element_by_name('number').clear()
    driver.find_element_by_name('number').send_keys('CGMU5109933')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="commit" and @value="Track direct"]').click()
    driver.save_screenshot('./x.png')

> python
>>> import foo
>>> foo.try_it()
```

**The code must be in a function** as it is called on demand when new search petitions arrive on a web service that is integrated in an application.

I always seek first for questions that may have valid answers but this time it doesn't seem to be anything similar to my problem.

Any idea why this may be happening and how to avoid it would be very much appreciated. If any other code or clarification is needed don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: I'm not seeing different behavior, and get useful results everytime. There does appear to be website behavior which differs -- sometimes it pops up 'Track direct" vs. "Track with options" message, sometimes not (in the x.png) but that may because sometimes the `save_screenshot` occurs before the popup is display & sometimes after. Suggest verifying your enviroment. Within `foo.py` print out version of selenium?

Comment: So in your enviroment, the image that you get executing the function shows correctly the webpage with the results (the popup you mention doesn't concern me that much). I suppose is logical, as the code is the same, but it leaves me with the same problem. Thanks for trying though !

Comment: I get an images with the tracking code entered -- depending on how quickly the screen_shot is taken, I get nothing else (as if browser hasn't reacted to click yet), or the popup regarding "Track with options". Same if a) entered into console; b) put as a non-function in foo.py; c) made into `try_it()` function in foo.py and called using `if __name__ == '__main__'`. So, the python code behaves as one would expect.

Comment: The expected behaviour is another webpage showing all the data about the container. So it seems that neither of the above options work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is purely a timing issue. Button clicks don't block, meaning once a click is issued, it returns and python runs the very next line right away. You need to wait until the next page has finished loading before you can take the screenshot. I would use an explicit wait that blocks until an element on the next page you're interested in has loaded. Likewise, I think you do need to worry about the popup asking if you really want to use direct.

My script:

```
from explicit import waiter
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


def locate_container(driver, container_id):
    url = 'http://www.track-trace.com/container'
    track_direct_xpath = '//input[@name="commit" and @value="Track direct"]'
    im_sure_css = 'div.modal-footer button.jq-directinfo-continue'
    tracking_details_header_css = 'div#wrapper > div.inner > h1'

    # Load the container search page
    driver.get(url)

    # Locate the container field, enter container_id, click direct search button
    waiter.find_write(driver, 'number', container_id, clear_first=True, by=By.NAME)
    waiter.find_element(driver, track_direct_xpath, By.XPATH).click()

    # Locate I'm Sure button and click it
    waiter.find_element(driver, im_sure_css, By.CSS_SELECTOR).click()

    # Wait for the "Tracking details for Container: XXX" header to load
    waiter.find_element(driver, tracking_details_header_css, By.CSS_SELECTOR)

    # Now we know the page has loaded and we can take the screenshot:
    driver.save_screenshot('./x.png')

def main():
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    try:
        driver.set_window_size(1280, 1024)
        locate_container(driver, 'CGMU5109933')
    finally:
        driver.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

(Full disclosure: I maintain the explicit package, which is meant to simplify using explicit waits. You can replace it with direct waits and get the same affect. Simply `pip install explicit` to install)

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your well written response and that elegant code. I would mark your answer as valid right away but I want to test it first thing in the morning (Monday). In my question I wrote that I had tried all type of waits I knew, and it didn't seem to work, even after a full minute. That is what was bugging me so much, a very simple search works fine line by line on console, but won't work when the button is clicked if it's wrapped in a function. I'll come back at you in a few days with the results of your code. Many thanks.

Comment: Hi again. I've just tried your code, and throws a TimeoutException on this line 
**waiter.find_element(driver, im_sure_css, By.CSS_SELECTOR).click()** 
I know that your code is correct, and this should work, so don't feel bad. It's just that the Track button is never ending to load, as my original question describes.

Comment: Interesting. If I switch to Chrome and run it, this is what I see: http://i.imgur.com/IZKh19k.gifv . How about you? If you are getting a timeout error, then I believe you may need to tweak your CSS path.

Comment: Watching how your code works on Chrome proves my point. PhantomJS is having trouble clicking that button and takes forever to load the page. I've even tried with Firefox and it's working too. PhantomJS seems to be the isue here.

Comment: I'll mark your answer as valid, as it's a well written answer and the code you show there works as intended, even though PhantomJS won't go through. Thanks a lot.